# JSON formatting not saved

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting

I add JSON to format my column and when I click "Preview" it looks fine.

Then I hit "Save" and close the format window but then the newly formatted column reverts back to the default and the JSON disappears.

This is the JSON I was adding:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.title",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "Silver",
    "color": "black",
    "padding-left": "10px"
  }
}
```

Comment: quite strange, what the column type you are targeting ? I tested your code on people column and it worked fine

Comment: the column type is contact. I'm not sure if this is related, but on some of the columns, the drop down arrow only shows "column settings" while other columns show "A to Z", "Z to A", "Filter by", "Group by Contact" and "Column settings >"